# How to match the variable of JQuery to PHP dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The result of dropdownlist is did not match what I wanted the data that has been selected. I would like to know how to pass the jquery or javascript variable to php or that is another to way to match the dropdownlist data?

```
    function editbtn(id){

        $('#employee_id_edit').val(id);

        var invoice_id = $('#user-user-list').find("#row_"+id).find("td:eq(1)").text();
        var payment_id = $('#user-user-list').find("#row_"+id).find("td:eq(2)").text();
        var category = $('#user-user-list').find("#row_"+id).find("td:eq(3)").text();
        var sale_person = $('#user-user-list').find("#row_"+id).find("td:eq(4)").text();
        var amount = $('#user-user-list').find("#row_"+id).find("td:eq(5)").text();
  
        $('#invoice_id_edit').val(invoice_id);
        $('#payment_id_edit').val(payment_id);
        $('#product_type_edit').val(category);
        $('#employee_edit').val(sale_person);
        $('#amount_edit').val(amount);  

    }
```

```
              <label for="employee">Sale Person</label>
              <select id="employee_edit" name="employee_edit" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        <?php
                        $employee_model = $registry->get('loader')->model('user');
                        $employee = $employee_model->getEmployee();
                        if(null !== $employee) {
                            foreach ($employee as $employee) {
                                ?>
                                <option  value="<?php echo $employee['username'];?>" selected><?php echo $employee['username']; ?></option>
                                <?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <option>No Employee Available</option>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
              </select>
```

Comment: Not really clear what the problem is other than "*not what I wanted*" which is as bad as "didn't work".   But looks like you should be putting the `id` in the `option value` rather than the `username` unless the usernames are unique (logins rather than names)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jquery plugins like 'jquery select2'(https://select2.org/)  or create some custom ajax request to send data from js to PHP backend and then get and handle a response from js part.